# How do I choose between passing a File, FileReader or BufferedReader object to a constructor of a class

Tags: java, constructor

Can anyone educate me a bit regarding passing a File, FileReader or BufferedReader object to a constructor of a class. 
Is there one which is generally speaking the better choice  or are there different situations where one is preferred over the other and if so what are these situations.
There is no code to show in regards to this question it is simply a matter of curiosity regarding the matter.

Comment: A reader must be closed - who's going to close it? A file is a path on your file system, a reader is a stream of characters from absolutely anywhere - what do you need to pass in?

Comment: Do you actually care if the data comes from a file? If not, don't require passing something related to files.

Comment: This is like asking "If someone requests a screwdriver, should I give them a slot, Phillips or Torx?".  The answer is it all depends on what you want to do, there's no "best" option.  Writing a complete explanation would be a tutorial, and StackOverflow is NOT a tutorial site or discussion site.

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely depends on your needs in each case.

A **File**-Object provides you with a set of methods to operate on a file in general, without reading or writing. You can find out its length, name and so on, create, delete or rename it.

A **FileReader**, as its name implies, reads the content of a file. In this case characters or strings.

A **BufferedReader** usually consumes a FileReader in order to control the amount of characters read at once.

For example:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
    new FileReader(
        file.getAbsolutePath()
    )
);
```